# how to Get access to shared mailbox using Microsoft Graphs

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to access shared mailbox using graphs?

I would like access shared mailbox mail folders using graphs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply treat it as any other user:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sharedaddress@microsoft.com/messages

Make sure you have the right permissions set (Mail.Read.Shared)

Comment: Thank you Ami. I have tried that earlier and it works. I also want to get a list of all shared mailbox using graphs without giving the shared mailbox user id or email address. Any workarounds?

Comment: No problem. 
There is no fool proof way of distinguishing shared mailboxes from normal users as of now. I figured you could filter on givenName eq null, since shared mailboxes don't have a givenName unless explicitly assigned one, but the api doesn't allow filtering on null. Depending on your situation you're best off assigning a keyword (like 'shared') as the givenName when creating shared mailboxes, or using the beta ["findroomlists" outlook api endpoint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/06/30/announcing-new-rest-apis-in-beta-for-rooms-time-zones-and-languages/)