# Access shared microsoft 365 mailbox through Microsoft Exchange in power bi

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to access a shared mailbox through Microsoft Exchange in power bi.
I got this
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration/shared-mailboxes/shared-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019#:~:text=A%20shared%20mailbox%20is%20a%20type%20of%20user%20mailbox%20that,t%20log%20into%20them%20directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration/shared-mailboxes/shared-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019#:%7E:text=A%20shared%20mailbox%20is%20a%20type%20of%20user%20mailbox%20that,t%20log%20into%20them%20directly).

in this link they said that
What are shared mailboxes?
**A shared mailbox is a type of user mailbox that doesn't have its own username and password.** As a result, users can't log into them directly.To access a shared mailbox, users must first be granted Send As or Full Access permissions to the mailbox. Once that's done, **users sign into their own mailboxes and then access the shared mailbox by adding it to their Outlook profile.** In Exchange 2003 and earlier, shared mailboxes were just a regular mailbox to which an administrator could grant delegate access. Beginning in Exchange 2007, shared mailboxes became their own recipient type:

RecipientType: UserMailbox

RecipientTypeDetails: SharedMailbox

so if shared mailbox doesn't have its own username and password then what we should provide in microsoft exchange when connecting to power bi?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Graph to access shared mailbox messages with this API Call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{sharedmailboxmailaddress}/messages
```

Although, you need to add and consent to required permissions for your own credentials to be able to access this from Graph. Its possible that this setting is controlled by your tenant admins.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/80006/shared-mailbox-handling-with-microsoft-graph.html

Comment: similar question is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719208/how-to-get-access-to-shared-mailbox-using-microsoft-graphs