# Powershell Get Emails from shared Mailbox on Exchange Online

Tags: powershell, email, exchange-server, windows-server

I want to read emails in the inbox of a shared Mailbox on Exchange Online with Powershell on a windows server to get data from the mailbody.

So far the methods I found:

1. EWS (no longer maintained)
2. Microsoft.Graph.Mail
3. IMAPX/MailKit
4. Outlook Application (not installed on the server)

But these methods are pretty complicated or seem not to work on shared Mailboxes.

Does anybody know a good solution for my problem ?

Kind regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

EWS still can be used, but `Graph API` is really what you need nowadays. See [Use the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I could not find a method to access a shared mailbox mail, in the documentation. Get-MgUserFolderMessage seems to work only for user mailboxes and not shared mailboxes ?

Comment: See [how to Get access to shared mailbox using Microsoft Graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719208/how-to-get-access-to-shared-mailbox-using-microsoft-graphs)